# Google Sheets - Get filtered row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I go about retrieving the values after filtering some data? It can either be accomplished through Google Scripts or a formula.

I have tried to use OFFSET, but it doesn't skip the "hidden" cells. Every method I have tried takes into account the hidden values created by the filtering

I have already filtered the rows correctly, i'm just looking to extract the data (first row only)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/filters#TOC-Get-filtered-rows). You might want to look into altering this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If FILTER table is in A1:G11,

H1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A11))
```

A13(First filtered Row):

```
=INDEX(A1:G11,SUBTOTAL(5,H2:H11))
```